# Error con el plugin Vegas

Tags: javascript, html5

Este es el código que estoy usando:
El plugin vegas no me está funcionando. 
No comprendo, qué me falta.

```
<!-- JQUERY versión 1.12.4 JS-->
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- HOJAS DE ESTILO -->
          <link href="/vegas/vegas.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- JAVA SCRIPTS UTILIZADOS-->
          <script src="/vegas/vegas.min.js"></script>       
  </head>

  <body>
   <!-- VEGA -->

      <div class="jumbotron vegas-container" id="jumbotron" style="height:600px;">
       <div class="vegas-slide vegas-transition-fade vegas-transition-fade-in vegas-transition-fade2-out" style="transition:all 1000ms;">
         <div class="vegas-slide-inner" style="background-image:url('/imagenes/banner02.png'); 
         background-color:rgb(238,238,238); background-size:cover; background-position: 50% 50%;">
         </div>
       </div> 
       <div class="vegas-slide vegas-transition-fade vegas-transition-fade-in vegas-transition-fade2-out" style="transition:all 1000ms;">
         <div class="vegas-slide-inner" style="background-image:url('/imagenes/banner06.png'); 
         background-color:rgb(238,238,238); background-size:cover; background-position: 50% 50%;">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="vegas-overlay"></div>
       <div class="vegas-timer vegas-timer-running">
         <div class="vegas-timer-progress" style="transition-duration: 4900ms;"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="vegas-wrapper" style="overflow:visible; padding: 48x 0x;">
         <div class="slide-home">
           <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">Aqui</h1>
            <p class="text-center">
             hola
             </p>
             </div>
             </div>
       </div>
     </div>     
  </body>
```

Comment: La consola del navegador te muestra algun error??, revisa si esta bien la dirección de tus archivos, intenta ingresando a `http://tusitio/vegas/vegas.min.js` y mira si te muestra el codigo fuente de la libreria.

Comment: No. La cónsola no me muestra ningún error y los vegas/*.js y *.css abren correctamente. Pareciera que no está el trigger para que se ejecute el código, se queda congelado, y no muestra ninguna imagen.

Comment: Pero lo que Juan quiere decir que esto `/vegas/vegas.min.css` no esta apuntando al local sino a una página en internet. Debería ser `../vegas/vegas.min.css`

Comment: Si. Las carpetas apuntan a mi directorio vegas en el servidor. De igual forma el problema sigue.

Comment: @Akyna es raro, porque si no lo consiguiera arrojaría un error. Haz probado de casualidad, el código en una página limpia?????

Comment: @Akyna Añade esto a tu head, y prueba si te funciona. `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.2.1/vegas.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.2.1/vegas.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: No. :( Gracias pero no. No tiene que ver con las librerías.

Comment: Aqui te dejo un jsfiddle funcional de vegas, revisalo a ver si te sirve: https://jsfiddle.net/rddmrb22/1/